# Replace <script src="url"> with <script>contents</script>

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm using simple_html_dom [ http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/ ] to parse through HTML.

I'm trying to get all of the `<script>` urls, grab the contents, and then replace it in the `$html` variable... I have this and it *almost* works like I want:

```
$html_elements = str_get_html( $html );
$current_src = array( );
$new_src = array( );
foreach($html_elements->find('script') as $element) {
    if( $element->src != '' )
    {
        $script_url = $element->src;

        $script_data = get_script( $script_url );

        $current_src[] = $element->outertext;
        $new_src[] = "<script>" . $element->innertext . "\n" . $script_data . "</script>";
    }
}

$html = str_replace( $current_src, $new_src, $html );

function get_script( $url )
{
  $data = file_get_contents( $url );
    return $data;
}
```

The problem is that it seems to be turning the plus signs in the javascript files in to spaces when it's all said and done?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, I can't see anything in your code that would convert + to space. Can you debug it and find out exactly where it happens?

Comment: @AbhiBeckert Thanks for the help! I was completely confused too!!! You were right, after a lot of debugging, I found out I had an extra `urldecode()` later on in the code that was the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the comment section above.

After further debugging, I was parsing the data one to many times through `urldecode()` later on in the code.